# how to fix wordpress high use cpu 100-104% evey time

Tags: memory

[image]

i try disable all plugin  or tye optimization database but still cpu 100%

how to fix solve ?

Comment: You have too many Apache process running, which in turn might be causing the high CPU and RAM usage.
Can you post the config for "IfModule mpm_prefork_module" from your apache2.conf here.

Comment: how to config  i use plesk

Comment: From your screenshot, I see you're able to SSH into your server. You should be able to edit your apache config in '/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'.

Be very careful if it's a live site, unless you've an experience.

Comment: i try config ifMoule but cpu still run 100%

Comment: Use Nginx Php-fpm module with ondemand setting. Set "pm.max_children = 100", "pm.max_requests = 5000". It will take some time to optimize php performence.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Previously, I used a2hosting hosting, it works fine all the time, but last Friday I received a notification email, cpu run is 100% .

So I tried migrating to vps, but it still cpu 100% as well.

now it still cpu run 100%

Comment: i try  install vps  LiteSpeed  and upgrade cpu and ram but it still run 100%